# Exceptions not working from outer procedure

Tags: mysql, mariadb, exception

I created a MySQL trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `check_purchase_date` BEFORE INSERT ON `purchases`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE purchase_date_in_future CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '45000';
    set time_zone='+5:30';
    IF date(NEW.purchase_date) > date(sysdate()) THEN
        SIGNAL purchase_date_in_future set message_text = 'Cannot purchase for future date.' ;
    END IF;
END
```

Then I created the below function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `new_purchase`(`v_purchase_date` DATE, `v_voucher_number` VARCHAR(25), `v_notes` TEXT) RETURNS int(11)
    MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO PURCHASES (PURCHASE_DATE, VOUCHER_NUMNER, NOTES)
    VALUES(v_purchase_date, v_voucher_number, v_notes);
    return last_insert_id();
END
```

When I insert something into the `purchases` with a future date, it throws the exception as expected.

But when I try to insert using the `new_purchase` function, the row isn't inserted but the exception isn't thrown as I expected.

What I get is:

> #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

This is when I run:

```
SELECT new_purchase(
'2016-12-30', NULL , NULL
);
```

If I try like:

```
SET @p0 =  '2016-12-28';

SET @p1 =  '';

SET @p2 =  '';

SELECT  `new_purchase` (
@p0 , @p1 , @p2
) AS  `new_purchase` ;
```

The data doesn't get inserted but no error is thrown at all. All I get is:

> Your SQL query has been executed successfully

Doesn't exceptions cascade in MySQL? If yes, how can I make sure an exception is cascaded?

Any help is appreciated. I am stuck with this for the past 2 days. :(

**DB Version:** 5.5.31-MariaDB-log

Comment: Which MariaDB version are you on, and what do you have in the config file?

Comment: Perhaps the `FUNCTION` should really be a `PROCEDURE`?

Comment: @RickJames Same happens whether I define a procedure or function. Also I have a requirement to return a value, so it has to be a function.

Comment: @elenst I am running on 5.5.31-MariaDB-log

Comment: Something is missing here. I tried it on 5.5.31, it works fine (and on recent releases, too). Maybe something in the server/client config that breaks it, or the sequence of events. I assume you're using MySQL client rather than any connector? Please paste the config files, output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE PURCHASES` and the whole output of a client session since connection start and till getting the error (as short as possible to get the error, but unabridged).

Comment: @elenst 

CREATE TABLE `purchases` (
 `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `voucher_number` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
 `purchase_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `purchase_status` enum('draft','posted') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'draft',
 `notes` text,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `voucher_number` (`voucher_number`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

Comment: @elenst I don't think how the create table is relevant though since the trigger works properly. Only thing is that the exception isn't getting cascaded properly.

Comment: Also, I am using phpMyAdmin to connect to the DB. I am not sure how to take the client session information"

Comment: @MathewParet, the table structure is most likely unimportant, but it never hurts to see it. For one, you have `voucher_number` in the table, but `VOUCHER_NUMNER` in the function, which is strange, they can't work together (I'll assume one of them is a typo). Anyway, I tried the same with phpMyAdmin, it also works fine; but different versions of phpMyAdmin are known to have weirdest problems. Can you connect to the server using MySQL command-line client (with the same credentials as phpMyAdmin) and run the queries there directly, just to make sure it's not the tool's fault?

Comment: The `voucher_number` was caused only when I pasted it here.

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly are you getting when you call the new_purchase() function with a future date?